# Role Based Authentication for web API not working

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, rbac

I'm facing an issue while working with Role-Based authentication for web APi.

I have a controller class where the controller has a custom authorize attribute called Myauthorize.
I have a method inside the controller which can be accessed only with Admin access.
But the same method has been calling with QA access as well.
Could anyone please help with the below?

Please find the code below.
Controller :

```
namespace Hosiptal.Controllers.office
{
 [MyAuthorize(Constants.Roles.Admin)]
 public class UserRolesController : ApiController
 {
    private readonly IRepository<EntityModels.Role> rolesRepository;

    public UserRolesController(IRepository<EntityModels.Role> rolesRepository)
    {            
        this.rolesRepository = rolesRepository;
    }

    // GET: Users
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]        
    public IEnumerable<Role> GetAll()
    {
        return this.rolesRepository.GetAll()
            .ToArray()
            .Select(r => Mapper.Current.Get<Role>(r));                
    }
  }
}
```

MyAuthorize has followed.

```
namespace Hospital.Web.Filters.WebApi
{

 public class MyAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute
 {
    private readonly string[] allowedroles;
    private static IUserProfileRepository UserProfileRepository
    {
        get { return IoC.Current.Resolve<IUserProfileRepository>(); }
    }
    public MyAuthorize(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.allowedroles = roles;
    }

    public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken 
      cancellationToken)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        
        var alias = claimsIdentity.Name.Split('@')[0];
        if (alias == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
        }
        user(alias);
        return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    public static GenericPrincipal user(string userName)
    {
        userName = userName.ToUpper();

        var userProfile = UserProfileRepository.Get(userName) ?? new UserProfile()
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Roles = new List<Role>(),
            FirstLoginDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        };
        return CreatePrincipal(userProfile);
    }
    public static GenericPrincipal CreatePrincipal(UserProfile user)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, 
                           user.UserName) }, "Custom");
        return new GenericPrincipal(identity, user.Roles.Select(i => 
              i.Name).ToArray());
    }
   }
 }
```

How can restrict the user here based on access level?

Comment: Why do you create the user with `user(alias);` if you are not assigning the value of the call to anything?

Comment: The way you have it, you might as well just use `[Authorize(Roles = "role1, role2, role3")]`

Comment: @insane_developer yes, I'm having other controllers that can be accessed with multiple roles.

Comment: @JuanR , sry I have added the code for user(alias)  method. Could you please check it once. I'm not understanding the roles mechanism here. Could you help ?

Comment: @Naurtosan have you tried `[Authorize(Constants.Roles.Admin)]`? That should do what you need. I thought you needed something besides checking for admin role, which this does.

Comment: @Naurtosan: I still see the same thing. The result of `user(alias)` is not stored anywhere.  Let me be clear, the code you are running in this method is **useless** right now because you are doing nothing with the result. I suspect that is where your issue lies.

Comment: @JuanR , So basically we are passing a token to access all Api's. In this MyAuthorize based on username we are fetching user roles and adding it to the username.

Comment: @Naurtosan: This is where you go wrong. You are creating an identity and a principal, buy you are **not** assigning them to anything so your current user within the context continues to be anonymous. That's why your authorization fails.

Comment: @JuanR, Could you help me here  with the code? I'm confusing here. Or if you any article link please ping here. I will check that

Comment: @Naurtosan: I posted an answer. Take a look when you have a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you review [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) for the `AuthorizeAttribute` class, you will see that it uses the controller context request's principal to perform authorization, so override the `IsAuthorized` method instead, move your code there and assign the principal you create to the context request's principal:

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var claimsIdentity = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

    var alias = claimsIdentity.Name.Split('@')[0];
    if (alias == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actionContext));
    }
    
    //This sets the context's principal so the base class code can validate
    actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal = user(alias);
    
    //Call the base class and let it work its magic
    return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
}
```

I will refrain from commenting on the design itself. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, @JuanR. The fix is working. Sorry for the late reply. You saved me. And always please share the knowledge with noobs like me :) .

Comment: @Naurtosan no worries. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working for me

```
public class AdminAuthorizeAttributee : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (AuthorizeRequest(actionContext))
        {
            return;
        }
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }

    private bool AuthorizeRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var user = userManager.Users.Where(a => a.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault();
            var rolesForUser = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id);
            var role = "Admin";



            if (rolesForUser.Contains(role))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

and in Controller

```
[AdminAuthorizeAttributee]
public class YOUR_Controller : ApiController
```

Comment: the one I'm looking for is with the roles based authentication

Comment: This is for role based authentication this function `userManager.GetRoles` will get you all the roles the user is in.

Comment: If you are looking for Claim based authentication this won't work !

Comment: Isn't this what `[Authorize(Constants.Roles.Admin)]` will do out of the box? Only users in the admin role have authorization to access the resource. I've done this repeatedly. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure, I always do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create your own authorize filter for this.
Use the built-in `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` - which will check if the user has a claim called "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" and if that value matches to the one you put in that authorize attribute, the authorization will succeed.

So in your case just make sure, when you log in the user to set his claim with the role like this:

```
            var claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"), //here set the users role
                     // ... other claims
            };
```

(`ClaimTypes` class is from the namespace `System.Security.Claims`)

And then the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` should work just fine

Comment: I am working on the web API authorization. So in myauthorize class only i can assign the roles to the user.But it is some where failing.

Comment: Can you share the code how do you 'log in' the user? How do you assign claims in that action?

Comment: As you see can the above code , we have the api's we are calling them by passing some Jwt token. The code which is in the Myauthorize class assigning the roles to the user. But Api has been calling with out the access of Admin user.